# Do we still need to include a "if (have_posts())" in templates?

Tags: posts, loop

I include this logic in my template all the time

```
if ( have_posts() ):
 //show content
else:
 //show content not found
endif;
```

But recently I began to doubt its necessity, WordPress will turn to 404.php when no post found, it seems no need to add this logic in normal templates, `else` will never be triggered, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I look at [`WP::handle_404()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L457), I think that the `404.php` template will not be loaded, even if there are no posts, if:

- We are on the homepage
- It is a search
- It is a taxonomy term that exists, but has no posts attached to it (and it's not paged)
- It is an author that exists, which has written no posts (yet) (and it's not paged)

So in these template files, `have_posts()` can be useful.

Comment: Makes sense. I've run into a case myself when loading the standard 404 template would not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

No, in most cases it's not needed.

`if ( have_posts() )` would only be useful on the index.php file, if you don't have a 404.php template.

And even in that case, you could use is_404() instead.

Comment: When I [look at the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L457), I see some cases where the `404.php` file will not be loaded. I provided details in my answer.