# Why Pagination is not working on Category.php

Tags: categories, pagination

There are two different category "Life Sciences" and "General Lab" and there are sub-categorical product on "Life Sciences".
Now "General Lab" category want to fetch all the sub-category and products which "Life sciences" have. The code is in category.php.
Here is the whole code:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( is_category('general-lab') ) : ?>

            <?php //FETCHING ONLY GENERAL LAB CATEGORY

                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                $the_query = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=10&category_name=life-sciences&paged=".$paged); ?>

                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo single_cat_title("", TRUE); ?></h1>

            <?php $count=0; while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php if($count % 2 == 0) echo '<div class="left">'; else echo '<div class="right">'; ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="cat-thumb"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_mcf_block-one', true); ?></div>
                    <div class="cat-entry">
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>     
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php if($count % 2 != 0) echo '<div class="clear"></div>';?>

            <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>

            <?php if (  $the_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span> ', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            </div><!-- #nav-below -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo single_cat_title("", TRUE); ?></h1>
        <?php $count=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if($count % 2 == 0) echo '<div class="left">'; else echo '<div class="right">'; ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <div class="cat-thumb"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_mcf_block-one', true); ?></div>
                <div class="cat-entry">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>     
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <?php if($count % 2 != 0) echo '<div class="clear"></div>';?>

        <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span> ', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            </div><!-- #nav-below -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->

    </div><!-- #container -->   

<?php $current_category = single_cat_title("", FALSE);
            $parent_cat = get_the_category();
            $back_to_current = get_cat_name($parent_cat[0]->category_parent);

if ( is_category( array( 'life-sciences','consumables','histology','forensics','pharmaceutical' ) ) == $current_category) { ?>
<?php echo '<div id="cat-menu"><h3>'.$back_to_current.'</h3>'; wp_nav_menu( array('container_id' => 'sub-page', 'menu' => $current_category ) ); echo '</div>';  } elseif ( is_category('general-lab')) { ?>
<?php echo '<div id="cat-menu"><h3>'.$current_category.'</h3>'; wp_nav_menu( array('container_id' => 'sub-page', 'menu' => $back_to_current ) ); echo '</div>'; } else { ?>
<?php echo '<div id="cat-menu"><h3>'.$back_to_current.'</h3>'; wp_nav_menu( array('container_id' => 'sub-page', 'menu' => $back_to_current ) ); echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: This may be your problem: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

Comment: see answer to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16353/custom-taxonomy-not-working-with-posts-per-page-in-new-wp-query-pagination-probl/16354#16354). `get_query_var('paged')` should be `get_query_var('page')` as of v3.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the second page of the "General Lab", WordPress does a query for posts in that category and finds none. If WordPress finds no posts, it will display the 404 template. The only case is [when you are on the *first* page of a taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/do-we-still-need-to-include-a-if-have-posts-in-templates/16407#16407) (like a category): then it still loads the specific template, allowing you to display a message like "No posts in this category". I explained this further in [an answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7687/pagination-with-wp-query-is-buggy-working-for-some-pages-but-not-the-others/7723#7723).

You should thus not do the query in the template, since it will be too late. Instead, hook into the `pre_get_posts` action:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse16387_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse16387_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( 'general-lab' == $wp_query->get( 'category' ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'category', 'life-sciences' );
        $GLOBALS['wpse16387_original_category'] = 'general-lab';
    }
}
```

Now it will load the `life-sciences` posts with the main query, and paging will work. You don't need the extra query in your template. You can detect you swapped the categories by reading the global `$wpse16387_original_category` variable.

Answer (score -2):

Please remove code:

```
<p style="text-decoration: line-through;">$paged = (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1);</p>
```

Use this one:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=10&category_name=life-sciences&paged=".**(get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)**); ?>
```

Comment: Please consult the [help] and see how to answering works. Please also use the [WYSIWYG](http://xkcd.com/1341/) editor buttons to format your content.

Comment: Never replace the main query with a custom one, it is **always** the cause of other problems. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query rather